# create an infinite recursive list in haskell using a function returning a sublist

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to resolve a project euler question. I want to create the list of element in an integer spiral.

I have the function:

```
next_four_numbers last size = map (\p -> last + p*(size-1)) [1,2,3,4]
```

- with parameters 1 and 3 it returns [3,5,7,9]
- with parameters 9 and 5 it returns [13,17,21,25]
- with parameters 25 and 7 it returns [31,37,43,49] ...

I certainly have other means to generate it, but in the end I want to have the infinite sequence:

diagonal_spiral_numbers = [1,3,5,7,9,13,17,21,25,31,37,43,49...]

How could I end up creating this infinte sequence using my "next_four_numbers" function? Of course I want it to be able to map this efficiently (I'd like to be able to do this for example):

```
take 20000 ( filter is_prime diagonal_spiral_numbers )
```

Thanks,

ps: of course I am learning haskell and it might be easier than I imagine.

Comment: I think the question isn't that clear. What list do you need, how should it contain? Could you post a link to the project?

Comment: This is Project Euler [Problem 58](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=58)

Comment: There's a typo, `n` should be `last` in `(\p -> n + p*(size-1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a function that generates the next state based on the previous one, you can then use the `iterate` function to create the entire list. In this case, the state consists of the four numbers and the size. After calling iterate, I call `map fst` to get rid of the `size` values, and `concat` to concatenate all the lists.

```
nextState (prev,size) = (next_four_numbers (last prev) size, size+2)
allNums = concat $ map fst $ iterate nextState ([1],3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
diagonal_spiral_numbers =
    let helper l s =
            let next_four_numbers last size = map (\p -> last + p*(size-1)) [1,2,3,4]
                (a:b:c:d:[]) = next_four_numbers l s
            in  a:b:c:d : helper d (s+2)
    in  1 : helper 1 3
```

Here the output:

```
take 20 diagonal_spiral_numbers
[1,3,5,7,9,13,17,21,25,31,37,43,49,57,65,73,81,91,101,111]
```

---

However I'm wondering why you need to use your `next_four_numbers` functions: the resulting list could be generated in many simpler (and I'd say overall *better*) ways.

Comment: This is just a snippet of code and offers no explanation, insight, or direction for how one could understand or derive such code.  -1

Comment: `[a,b,c,d] = ...` is a more readable way (imho) to match a four-element list.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly can be done that way, generating a list of lists and then [flattening](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/PLE/haskell/haskell-sol.html) it (check out the concatMap function), but the usual way is to have your helper function take an additional "tail" argument, and then return a:b:c:d:tail.

Another approach would be to use zipWith3.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your `last` and `size` parameters are always of the form `(2x+1)^2` and `2x+3`, respectively (for `x` in `0,1,2,3,...`)

You just need to call next_four_numbers once with each of these parameters.  This can be accomplished with a list comprehension:

```
diagonals = [next_four_numbers ((2*x+1)*(2*x+1)) (2*x+3) | x <- [0..]]
```

Or with a map (if you're more comfortable with that):

```
diagonals = map (\x -> next_four_numbers ((2*x+1)*(2*x+1)) (2*x+3)) [0..]
```

Then it's just a matter of flattening the list and prepending 1:

```
actual_diagonals = 1:concat diagonals
main = print (take 20 actual_diagonals)
```

This can probably be cleaned up a bit, but I'll leave that to you ;)
BTW, `[0..]` is just shorthand for the infinite list `0,1,2,3,...`